# The second homologygroup of a orientable three manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology

If a short question:
I have a closed orientable 3-Manifold, which has a perfect fundamental group.

therfore $H_1(M)=0,H_0(M)=H_3(M)=\mathbb{Z}$ somehow it seems like i can conclude that $H_2(M)=0$, but i don't know how to conclude this.
by Poincaire duality I could say that $b_2=0$ but why cant there be Torsion.

Comment: You can also use the universal coefficient theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The torsion parts of $H^3(M) = \mathbb{Z}$ and $H_2(M)$ coincide by the universal coefficient theorem.

Comment: More generally, if $M$ is a closed $n$-dimensional orientable manifold, $H_{n-1}(M; \mathbb{Z})$ is free.

Comment: Sure: The proof is the same. (I think it's also an exercise or minor result in Hatcher.)